# help with a jquery selector

Tags: jquery

I've got this dom:

```
<a class='foundTag' id=261 href=''>
    <span class=name>wimbledon<\/span>
    <span class=subscribers>(0)<\/span>
    <span class=threads>(0)<\/span>
<\/a>
<a id=263 href=''>
    <span class=name>wini<\/span>
    <span class=subscribers>(0)<\/span>
    <span class=threads>(0)<\/span>
<\/a>
```

It's 2 links, the first one with `class='foundTag'` (the spans are inside the links). I want to select the next tag and alert its id.  I used:

```
 alert($('a.foundTag').next().attr('id'));
```

but it didn't work. Do you guys know why?

UPDATE: sorry guys...my bad..the first link was not a sibling to the second one. so next() wouldnt work. i had to use parent().next().children(':first') instead.

should we close this thread?

Comment: Might be because your end tags are strange.

Comment: If you're really closing your tags with "<\/span>" and "<\/a>" instead of "</span>" and "</a>", stop :-)

Comment: its jquery ajax embedded..it should be like that when entering javascript from php i think. or it will break the dom.

Comment: @svinto, I was halfway through editing those (from `<\/span>` to `</span>`) before it occurred to me there *could* be a reason why. I have no idea what that might be, though.

Comment: @noname, jQuery acts on the html tags present in the rendered document, check and see what the source html is of the finished/rendered page, and post that.

Comment: See your source code from the browser .. if it has the `\/` then it is wrong..

Comment: @gaby and @ricebowl...cant check the source...not when its ajax embedded.

Comment: @noname: You can either alert it before it is embedded or use firebug.

Comment: @noname or use firefox web developer plugin and *view generated source*..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works if you change the escaped ending tags with normal ending tags. Make sure jQuery is loaded. Also it is possible you have a javascript error above, try to segregate it.

Comment: those escaping characters are added automatically. i echo out the right format from php file to jquery ajax but it escapes like that. they are all displayed correctly in the web browser. it should be like that i guess...try echo out a link from php ... it will be automatically escaped...use firebug to check.